# Can it be traced the texts you copied on internet from your local computer?

Tags: networking, copy-paste

Suppose I copy and paste some texts or code from my local computer's notepad or some text editor and directly paste it in online editor like ideone.com . Can it be traced ? If yes, How ?

**Example**:
2 developer connected to company network as well as internet (Not directly but using a "**Use automatic configuration scrip**t" in *Internet Options->Connections->LAN Settings*

**Use Case:**

1. 1 developer is copying code from his local editor and pasting on online editor (ideone.com).
2. Other developer directly writing the code in online editor.

**As a Network Administrator point of View:**
How to trace and avoid those two case ?

**As a Developer point of View:**
How to check if the Admin have enabled such things to be traced ?

If it is enabled, how to be not traced ?

Comment: You can trace the Windows Clipboard via the Microsoft API. You have to elaborate further about the use case so that we can suggest a specific class/method.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, there are many methods. I will name a few.

1. Some JS scripts. The website can detect what you are copying.
2. MITM attacks on the network you are using. Wifi with no password is the most dangerous one. Using CSploit on an android phone anyone can see your traffic.
3. Some keyloggers and other viruses can log keyboard and copy-paste activity.
4. Remote administration apps and malwares can stream your screen to the hacker.